# Android Kotlin Save Image to Directory

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm creating android apps using kotlin that user select image from gallery and save to "demoapps" directory. here my script

```
package com.akademik.pilihgaleri

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btn_select:Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_select)
        val btn_upload:Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_upload)


        btn_select.setOnClickListener {
            val open_galeri = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            pilih_gambar.launch(open_galeri)
        }

        btn_upload.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }

    private val pilih_gambar = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        val selectedImage:ImageView = findViewById(R.id.selected_image)
        if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val data = it.data
            if (data != null) {
                val imgUri = data.data
                selectedImage.setImageURI(imgUri)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

that script works fine to select image from gallery and displaying into imageview.

**how to save that selected image to "demoapps" directory? when btn_upload clicked**

Comment: Why are you calling that an upload button?